# How i can save all the id's values in an array?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with 941 documents. I want create a collection with only 1 document and the field ids. The value of the field is expected to be an array of all the ids of the previous collection. I'm using the $out in mongo for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) with [**`$push`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) accumulator to get the array of all the documents `_id`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "ids": { "$push": "$_id" }
  }},
  { "$out": "newCollectionName" }
])
```